# Creating a admin page with php and not sending to admin page going to user account page

Tags: php, html, authentication, admin

Login3.php

```
include 'init.php';
include 'functions.php';

$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$username = clean_string($username);
$password = clean_string($password);
$error_check = array();

if (empty($username)) {
    $error_check[] = 'Please enter a username';
}
if (empty($password)) {
    $error_check[] = 'Please enter a password';
}

if (empty($error_check)) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['UserID'];
        if ($row['UserID'] == 1) {
            header('Location:admin.php');
        } else {
            header('location:login.php');
        }
    } else {
        $error_check[] = 'Please enter correct details';
        $_SESSION['errors'] = $error_check;
        header('location:login.php');
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $error_check;
    header('location:login.php');
}
?>
```

admin.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'connected.php';
var_dump($_SESSION);
if (isset($_SESSION['UserID']) && $_SESSION['UserID'] == 1){
    echo "Welcome. Accessed";
} else {
    header('location:login.php');
    //exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My first Web page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/final_index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="header">
                <div class="span1"> </div>
                <header>
                    <img id="banner" src="images/safc.banner.PNG" alt="banner">
                </header>

            </div>

            <div class="banner1">

            </div>

        </br>


            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Sunderland</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="final_index.php">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="shop.php">Shop</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="reg.php">Register</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="protect.php">Protected Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="login1">
                <div id="login1"

                <div class="grid20">

            <h2>Admin</h2>
            <h4>Edit Users Details</h4>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <lable for ="Username" > Username: </lable> </br>
        <input type="text" name="Username" value=''/> </br>
        <lable for ="Password" > Password: </lable> </br>
        <input type="password" name="Password" /> </br>
        <lable for ="Email" > Email: </lable> </br>
        <input type="email" name="Email" /> </br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        <input type="reset"  value="clear" />
    </form>

    <h4>Add User </h4>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <lable for ="Username" > Username: </lable> </br>
        <input type="text" name="Username" value=''/> </br>
        <lable for ="Password" > Password: </lable> </br>
        <input type="password" name="Password" /> </br>
        <lable for ="Email" > Email: </lable> </br>
        <input type="email" name="Email" /> </br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        <input type="reset"  value="clear" />
    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
            </div>



                    </div>
                    </div>
            </body>

</html>
```

this code is supposed to check if a user is a admin or general when logged in as admin will take you to admin page and if not admin will take you to user account page when i log in as admin it always takes me to the user account not admin page

Comment: What is the value of `$row['UserID']`?

Comment: every user in my database is assigned a userID and im trying to create the page so that it detects userID 1 as the admin so this code is trying to connect to the database and pick up which user has the 1 then redirect him to the correct page

Comment: Why do you have two files `login.php` and `Login3.php`? Are they same?

Answer (score 3):

In your code you set:

```
$_SESSION['User_ID']
```

But then, you are checking:

```
$_SESSION['UserID']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're setting the User ID session variable with an **$_SESSION['User_ID']** and then testing it on the Admin screen without the underscore.